# can you test mouse movement with cypress?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

For a photo editor I'm working on I need to test how a mouse interacts with my canvas.
Some examples are

- checking if the right element is highlighted in a canvas on hover
- dragging elements around on my canvas and checking if they moved by the correct amount

Is it possible to test these types of interaction with cypress, or will I need to move over to a selenium based testing framework?

I know that through the `.trigger` method I can call a mouse move event, but it seems to be instant instead of gradually moving the mouse to the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [hover()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover) for test hovering and a library for supporting drag&drop like [cypress-drag-drop](https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop)